# Reading and grouping data to get count using python spark

Tags: python, pyspark

I'm new to spark using python and I'm trying to do some basic stuff to get an understanding of python and spark.

I have a file like below -

```
empid||deptid||salary
1||10||500
2||10||200
3||20||300
4||20||400
5||20||100
```

I want to write a small python spark to read the print the count of employees in each department.

I've been working with databases and this is quite simple in a sql, but I'm trying to do this using python spark. I don't have a code to share as I'm completely new to python and spark, but wanted to understand how it works using a simple hands-on example

I've install pyspark and did some quick reading here https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/quick-start.html

Form my understanding there are dataframes on which one can perform sql like group by, but not sure how to write a proper code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can read the text file as a dataframe using :

```py
df = spark.createDataFrame(
    sc.textFile("path/to/my/file").map(lambda l: l.split(',')),
    ["empid","deptid","salary"]
)
```

`textFile` loads the data sample as an `RDD` with only one column. Then we split each line through a `map` and convert it to a dataframe.

Starting from a python list of lists:

```py
df = spark.createDataFrame(
    sc.parallelize([[1,10,500],
                    [2,10,200],
                    [3,20,300],
                    [4,20,400],
                    [5,20,100]]),
    ["empid","deptid","salary"]
)

df.show()

    +-----+------+------+
    |empid|deptid|salary|
    +-----+------+------+
    |    1|    10|   500|
    |    2|    10|   200|
    |    3|    20|   300|
    |    4|    20|   400|
    |    5|    20|   100|
    +-----+------+------+
```

Now to count the number of employees by department we'll use a `groupBy` and then use the `count` aggregation function:

df_agg =  df.groupBy("deptid").count().show()

```py
    +------+-----+
    |deptid|count|
    +------+-----+
    |    10|    2|
    |    20|    3|
    +------+-----+
```

For the max:

```py
import pyspark.sql.functions as psf
df_agg.agg(psf.max("count")).show()
```

Comment: df.groupBy("deptid").count().show() -> gives me all the count, but if I need the max value of count ?

df.groupBy("deptid").count().max().show() -> doesnt work

@Marie

Comment: I added the part with the maximum value of `count`